Issue with "invalid opcode" error in Ethereum smart contract
I'm having an issue with an "invalid opcode" error in my Ethereum smart contract. Deployment and getNumber calls work, but setName results in an error when retrieving the name.
Solidity Contract:
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

contract Construct {
    uint256 private number;
    string private name;

    constructor(uint256 _number) {
        number = _number;
    }

    function getNumber() public view returns (uint256) {
        return number;
    }

    function setNumber(uint256 _number) public {
        number = _number;
    }

    function getName() public view returns (string memory) {
        return name;
    }

    function setName(string memory _name) public {
        name = _name;
    }
}

Ruby Script:
require 'eth'
require 'forwardable'

client = Eth::Client.create('http://127.0.0.1:8545')
contract_address = "0x459E0a953e6fAe85b248017b7c4484500b08F57C"
contract = Eth::Contract.from_file(file: '../contracts/construct.sol')
tester_contract = Eth::Contract.from_abi(name: "Construct", address: contract_address, abi: contract.abi)

deployer_account = Eth::Key.new(priv: '0xc1f3f4d9fd9a7fe90b966825a780697a400c675e56f9153ed21bc045c0e7207e')

balance = client.eth_get_balance(deployer_account.address)
puts "Deployer account balance: #{balance['result'].to_i(16) / 1e18} ETH"

client.max_fee_per_gas = 41_000_000_000
client.max_priority_fee_per_gas = 4_000_000_000

# Call the getNumber function
begin
  response = client.call(tester_contract, "getNumber")
  puts "Current number: #{response}"
rescue StandardError => e
  puts "Error while getting number: #{e.message}"
  puts e.backtrace
end

# Call the setNumber function
begin
  response = client.transact_and_wait(tester_contract, "setNumber", 12345, sender_key: deployer_account, gas_limit: 10_000_000)
  puts "Transaction hash for setNumber: #{response}"
rescue StandardError => e
  puts "Error while calling setNumber: #{e.message}"
  puts e.backtrace
end

# Call the setName function
begin
  response = client.transact_and_wait(tester_contract, "setName", "huy", sender_key: deployer_account, gas_limit: 10_000_000)
  puts "Transaction hash for setName: #{response}"
rescue StandardError => e
  puts "Error while calling setName: #{e.message}"
  puts e.backtrace
end

# Call the getName function
begin
  response = client.call(tester_contract, "getName")
  puts "Current name: #{response}"
rescue StandardError => e
  puts "Error while getting name: #{e.message}"
  puts e.backtrace
end

Additional Context:

The number works fine, indicating the contract is deployed correctly.
The "invalid opcode" error suggests the issue might be with the setName or getName functions or how strings are being handled.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Have you deployed your contract using Remix IDE? If yes, what’s the compiler and EVM version that you’ve selected from the compiler configuration settings?

Post the entire error message .
